# How to display pictures in express/node out of root directory (from USB key)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm creating a "media center" for raspberry pi with node.js/express framework and I've encountered the problem.

I know how to read files from another path and all.... I display their names/info on the website without the problem using chokidar, but for example when I want to display image on the website using the file's path -

> img(src="/media/dude/foo/bar.jpg")

I get blank pic - If i right click on it it says

> Error: Not Found

I added

> app.use(express.static('/media/dude/foo'));

to app.js file, but it didn't help at all :/

**Basically I need to be able to display pictures on a website that are out of my app's root directory - that are located on my USB drive.**

Has anyone got any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `/media/dude/foo` as root for static files, you shouldn't include the root directory path in the `img` tag (because the root directory is mapped to "/").

In other words, try this:

```
# app.js
app.use(express.static('/media/dude/foo'));

# your template
img(src="/bar.jpg")
```

Similarly, if you used `/media/dude` as root, you'd use `/foo/bar.jpg` in your template.